# Best way to round a Dictionary key represented by a float in Python with a given precision

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists like

```
firstlist = [[x1,12.0,text,0.05],[x2,12.0,text,0.08],[x3,14.0,text,0.05],[x4,16.0,text,0.05],[x5,12.0,text,0.08]]
```

I tried to create a dictionary like

```
mydict = {0.05:[[x1,12.0,text,0.05],[x3,14.0,text,0.05],[x4,16.0,text,0.05]],
          0.08:[[x2,12.0,text,0.08],[x5,12.0,text,0.08]]}


d = {}
for row in FirstList[1:]:
    # Add name to dict if not exists
    if len(row)==13:
        if row[12] not in d:
            d[row[12]] = []
            # Add all non-Name attributes as a new list
        d[row[12]].append(row[1:])
```

where keys represent commissions.

My problem is that some commissions are very close resulting more rows.

for example

```
 mydict = {0.05:[[x1,12.0,text,0.05],[x3,14.0,text,0.05],[x4,16.0,text,0.05]],
           0.048:[[x2,12.0,text,0.048],[x5,12.0,text,0.048]],
           0.051:[[x2,12.0,text,0.051],[x5,12.0,text,0.051]]}
```

how to have the keys for example if keys are 0.049 or 0.051 with a difference of 0.01-0.02 and close to 0.050 to be 0.05

Comment: What if you have keys 0.050, 0.051, 0.052, 0.053, 0.054, 0.055, 0.056, 0.057, 0.058, 0.059, 0.060? How do you want to combine them? How do you draw the line?

Comment: I would think 0.05 +- 0.001, 0.052 +- 0.001, 0.054 +- 0.001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the value at index `12` as key for the dictionary.  You can round the value before passing it as the key.

```
d = {}
for row in FirstList[1:]:
    # Add name to dict if not exists
    if len(row)==13:
        key = round(row[12], 2)
        if key not in d:
            d[row[12]] = []
            # Add all non-Name attributes as a new list
        d[key].append(row[1:])
```

To handle the segmentation you posted in the comments, with keys on event numbers in the thousandths decimal place, you need to do some math to generate the key.

Essentially, you have 5 bins between each hundredth decimal place to you need to round the values into.  We can accomplish this by multiplying by 5, rounding, dividing by 5, and rounding again (to clip the value).

```
def nearest_even_1000th(x):
    return round(round(x * 5, 2) / 5, 3)

d = {}
for row in FirstList[1:]:
    # Add name to dict if not exists
    if len(row)==13:
        key = nearest_even_1000th(row[12])
        if key not in d:
            d[row[12]] = []
            # Add all non-Name attributes as a new list
        d[key].append(row[1:])
```

Comment: What if I want  0.05 +- 0.001, 0.052 +- 0.001, 0.053 +- 0.001

Comment: That is a different question altogether.  What does 0.0524 get assigned to?

Comment: I have 3 decimal places which means a 0.052 is a 5.2% as a commission. If I had a 5.24% I would like it to be 5.2%. How to round them in closest even ? A 0.053 to 0.054

Comment: Right, but you have  0.052 +- 0.001 and 0.053 +- 0.001 in your first comment.  0.0524 falls into the bounds of BOTH of those ranges.

Comment: Yes you are correct I meant .52 .54 .56..

Comment: See the update in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need the builtin function [round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round)

```py
round(0.05, 2)  # 0.05
round(0.048, 2) # 0.05
round(0.051, 2) # 0.05
```